# Spring - Getting config values from another file

Tags: java, spring, properties, config, environment

I have a Spring application where in I need to access certain credentials. To keep them stored secretly, in my `application.properties` I only declare the path to the file where the credentials are stored. The file with the credentials themselves are stored on the machine that the application will be running on.

I somewhere, at sometime, read that it could be possible to use the following to get property values:

```
*(from the application.properties file...)*
example.setting1=${file:/path/to/file.properties:onevalue}
example.setting2=${file:/path/to/file.properties:another.value}
example.setting3=${file:/path/to/file.properties:a.third.value}
```

In code I then use `org.springframework.core.env.Environment#getProperty(key)` to get the property values from my application.properties. I thought this would work and return the value that is stored in the `/path/to/file.properties` file, but instead it returns the actual value in my application.properties, being this: `example.setting1=${file:/path/to/file.properties:onevalue}`.

How can I solve this and have the program return the actual credential (*for example an IP "0.0.0.0"*) that is stored in the target file the Spring app config has the path to?
Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `spring.config.import` which would import the values from the given file(s)

Comment: may be there is some conflict with keyword ```file```  in spring  ,try to use another keywork , not  ```file```  ,just   use ```credentials.file.path``` instead ,

Comment: Alternatively, you can  try add  java application start vm optition ```java -jar myapp.jar --file=/custom/path```

Comment: oh  , if it is  necessary that define double : in your value string ,you can store it  in a file  and  configure the file path in spring ,then  read the file  to get the defaultvalue ```/path/to/file.properties:onevalue```

Comment: @CodeMatrix That was something I hadn't tried. I tried it, and it worked perfectly, thank you! I import all property values from all files on the machine using `spring.config.import` and then access them just like I did before with no code change. Extremely nice, thank you again!

Comment: Take a look at how spring is loading properties. It supports external application.properties out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it fixed by adding another property value to my `application.properties` being `spring.config.import`.

Using `spring.config.import` it's possible to import the files stored on the target machine and the properties in those files. For example like this: `spring.config.import=file:/path/to/file.properties,file:/path/to/anotherfile.properties`.

After that, it's possible to use the same `org.springframework.core.env.Environment#getProperty(key)` code and get the values from the imported config files: `Environment#getProperty("onevalue")` and `Environment#getProperty("another.value")`.